# delphi mysql offline connection

Tags: mysql, delphi, connection, offline

I wonder whether it is possible to read data from mysql database **not remotely from server**, but just **from a file** on my disk, like from .mdb files. A happened to work with 2010 Office which gives .accmdb files rather then .mdb and cannot convert them, that's why I switched to mysql.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: emm, I want to connect mysql db to delphi. Please read the whole question. It's mostly a delphi problem, for sure.

Comment: What does offline mean to you in this context?  A database connection to MySQL can be to a remote server, or to a local database on your own disk.  This is not the same thing as "going offline". In the database world, a better way of asking this question might be to ask about "a briefcase model". Describe exactly what it is you want to do, and you'll get better answers.  This question seems very confused, and vague to me as it stands.  "Embedded server" may be what you want but I can't tell from your question. Explain exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use MySQL Embedded server. That will be similar to how you are working with Microsoft Access. AFAIK, Anydac supports MySQL Embedded server. May be other libraries too.
2. But I does not see a reason to replace Access with MySQL. To work with .accdb files you need to use different OLEDB provider (I expect you are using ADO) - "Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider" or similar.